# Migrating to Google Play Billing Library Version 5.1.0 - SkuDetails.getOriginalJson() equivalent

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I am upgrading from Google Play Billing version 4.0.0 to version 5.1.0.
In version 4 `SkuDetails` has the function `getOriginalJson()` that contains a json object that I send to my back end. I dug in the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails) and could not find an official equivalent in version 5.1.0.

There are 2 places where I can see that this information may be available in `com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetails` - an interal `JSONObject` member that we are not supposed to access and as part of the `toString()` function where this information is appended to `parsedJson`. I can probably extract what I need from the `toString()`, but I was wondering if there something better/official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accessible in class `Purchase`.

```
Purchase.getOriginalJson();
```

Places you can access it:

```
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            QueryPurchasesParams queryPurchasesParams = QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build();
            billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(queryPurchasesParams, (billingResult1, list) -> runOnUiThread(() -> {
                for (Purchase purchase: list) {
                    Log.d("originalJson", purchase.getOriginalJson());
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() { }
});
```

And:

```
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase: purchases) {
                Log.d("originalJson", purchase.getOriginalJson());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.